# Does Windows Small Business Server 2008 include DFSR?

Tags: windows, windows-sbs-2008, dfs-r

Does Windows Small Business Server 2008 Standard include DFSR?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it does, according to the [**Windows Small Business Server 2008 Technical FAQ**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sbs/cc817589.aspx), but without the management tools.  Under the **Backup and Server Storage** heading look at the answer to the question "Does Windows Small Business Server 2008 support Distributed File System (DFS) for data replication?"

> DFS is built into Windows Server 2008
>   and is available in Windows Small
>   Business Server 2008. If you want to
>   use DFS you must use the
>   technology-specific tools in Windows
>   Server 2008 as there are no tools for
>   configuring or managing DFS in the
>   Administration Console.